# problema con la visibilidad de una lista en una tabla

Tags: java

la lista contiene unos registros y al darle click se agrega a la tabla pero la tabla se sobrepone a la lista [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se si exista una propiedad de la tabla que me permita quitar eso o de la lista para que no suceda

este es el código de la lista

```
private void Lista2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    Modelo = (DefaultTableModel) TablaVentas.getModel();
    String nombrepuesto;
    int size = 0, cont = 0;
    String name = Lista2.getSelectedValue();
    BuscarRespuesto.setText(name);
    size = Modelo.getRowCount();

    if (size == 0) {
        MostrarVentas(name);
        Calcular();
    } else {
        if (size == 26) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "disculpe solo 26 repuestos", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            size = Modelo.getRowCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < Modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {
                nombrepuesto = (String) Modelo.getValueAt(i, 2);
                if (!name.equals(nombrepuesto)) {
                    cont = 1;
                } else {
                    cont = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (cont == 1) {
                if (size > 26) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "disculpe solo 26 repuestos", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    MostrarVentas(name);
                    Calcular();
                }
            } else {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ya selecciono ese repuesto", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

use el evento del click para ir agregando a la tabla, le envio al mostrar por parámetro el nombre y este lo muestra junto con los otros registros

la jerarquía [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías explicar mas detalladamente como has construido la interfaz y adjuntar código para verlo mas claro ? Un saludo!

Comment: listo @PabloPérez-Aradros

Comment: nose si lo he interpretado bien, la lista se despliega y aun asi la tabla se muestra por encima no ?

Comment: si, exacto se muestra por encima @PabloPérez-Aradros

Comment: podrias adjuntar una captura de la jerarquia de los elementos de la interfaz ?

Comment: ya @PabloPérez-Aradros

Comment: pues no se muy bien porque te puede estar pasando eso... a ver si ve la entrada alguien que sepa porque

Comment: Intenta poner la propiedad opaque de la lista en true.